# Downloading and saving a file from Android app link

Tags: java, android, jsp, android-studio

I have done a simple web link to a JSP page and trying to download and save a file on click of a button in JSP page. I had given access permission for storage, but I am not getting the file to download and save. Any changes in JSP are also welcome. Any suggestions?